# autocorrelation for truncated normal distribution

Tags: autocorrelation, truncated-normal-distribution

I have a (symmetric) truncated normal distribution from which I'm sampling.  There is also auto-correlation of the values, so I know:

$\mu, \sigma,$ autocorr = $a$

All three of these values are single-valued.  E.g., $\mu_R$ = 1, $\sigma_R$ = 1, $a_R$ = 0.5

My understanding of the application of autocorrelation to a series, $R \sim N(\mu_R=1,\sigma_R=1)$, with the normal distribution results in the new series $S$ as:

$S(1) = R(1)$

$$
S(i) = a_R\cdot R(i-1) + w(i),
$$

Where $w(i) \sim N(0,\sigma_w) $
(taken from these notes - [http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~godwinrt/7010/topic8.pdf](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/%7Egodwinrt/7010/topic8.pdf))

However, I have also seen this formulation:

$R \sim N(\mu_R=1,\sigma_R=1)$

$b = \sqrt{1-a_R^2}$

$S(1) = R(1)$

$$
S(i) = a_R \cdot S(i-1) + b \cdot R(i)
$$

Where does the $b$ come from?

Why are we scaling the second term instead of drawing from $w(i)$?

Why is the autocorrelation coefficient recursively applied via the first term? (e.g., $S(2)\approx a_R\cdot S(1);  
S(3)\approx (a_R\cdot S(2)) \approx a_R\cdot (a_R\cdot S(1))$)

The only example I've found is this:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2894681/how-to-transform-shift-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-of-a-normal-distribution

But it doesn't fully explain these questions.